# passing data from a service to a view template in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an email confirmation for orders that get placed on a website. I have the following that holds the order information:

```
        IOrder order = null;
        if (response.Data != null)
        {
            order = FillOrder(response.Data);
        }
```

There's more code before this but this fills an object that holds all of our order data for the order. Next I call into a service that takes a view template as a parameter to format the email, my question is this; How would I go about passing data into the view template from this service being that it isn't really a model or anything like that so that I can actually get a properly formatted view template to pass into the email service I've made? Let me know if that makes any sense and if not I'll try to re-word it, thanks.

Edit: My question has nothing to do with formatting the email I'm needing to send out, so let me re-word the problem this way; I need to pass the order information into a partial view, I already have the code working that takes the partial view and formats the email, so I just need to know how I can pass data to the view without the thing passing the data being a controller or a model.

Comment: No it's really not clear. Consider posting your other services code where you pass viewtemplate and how this order data you want to pass along with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your edit, looks like you just want to have the `Order` information in your action method. If so then you have two choice:

1. In your controller action method, directly call this posted method which returns the `Order` instance and pass it to the partial view.
2. Create a view model, which will have a property of type `IOrder`. In your action method call the service and fill that viewmodel property. In turn pass he view model to the partial view as model.
3. If you don't want any model to be associated with view then call the service and attach it's return value to `ViewBag` object like

   `IOrder order = serviceOrderMethod();
   ViewBag.Order = order;`

Use the same in your partial view saying

```
@ViewBag.Order
```